# print to minibuffer without requiring user input in vim

Tags: python, vim

Take this code snippet for an example:

```
function! Myecho()
python <<EOF
print("hi there")
EOF
endfunction
```

If I do `:w | so % | call Myecho()`, a line of text will appear in the minibuffer:

[image]
<sub>(source: [p.im9.eu](http://p.im9.eu/host1406651429-809311.jpg))</sub>

And it waits for the user to press return. I am wondering how I can print a line to minibuffer without needing user input?

Answer (score 3):

That message appears because the output of your command exceeds the height of the command-line (not "minibuffer"). Judging by the content of your command-line, you didn't do `:so % | call Myecho()` but `:w | so % | call Myecho()` or some variation.

You can augment the size of the command-line:

```
:set cmdheight=2
```

or do the two operations separately:

```
:w
:so % | call MyEcho()
```

See `:help press-enter` and, possibly `:help 'shortmess'` that you seem to have read already.

Comment: Nice. but i am looking for a more general solution, a method to print arbitrary message to the minibuffer without requiring user's input.

Comment: @qed Can you explain what you mean by minibuffer? Is it different than what romainl is talking about? Do you want the person to be able to read the message you are printing? Without the `Press ENTER or type command to continue` message you might not be able to read your message

Comment: Is it possible to set a max-height property for the commandline window, for example, 5 lines, so that the commandline window height will automatically adjust to the message?